# assignment operator for a function return

Tags: python

Clearly, it may not make that much sense to make an assignment to a function return, yet I've just encountered a strange situation and could not find a proper rule for that.
The code below does not run:

```
def foo():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    return a

foo()= 10
```

however,

```
def foo():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    return a

foo()[2] = 10
```

works perfectly. It is not clear to me what is going on here. It looks to me that there is an inconsistency here...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you want to make a function assign  a value?

Comment: @Marc to learn. I am saying over there that "it may not make sense"...

Answer (score 2):

> It is not clear to me what is going on here.

It's fairly simple, really; the left-hand-side of an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) is not allowed to just be any kind of expression, but some "kinds" of expression are valid assignment targets, and for those kinds of expression **it doesn't matter what kinds of sub-expressions they may have**. In your example, the left-hand-side is a [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-subscription), which is a valid assignment target, so it's a syntactically valid assignment statement.

In particular, a subscription has two sub-expressions but it doesn't matter what lexical form those sub-expressions have. For example, the below may look perfectly normal to you, where the first sub-expression `foo.bar` is an [attributeref](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-attributeref) and the second sub-expression `index + 5` is an [a_expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-a_expr):

```py
foo.bar[index + 5] = value
```

This example probably also looks perfectly normal: the first sub-expression `baz[get_x()]` is another subscription, and the second sub-expression `get_y()` is a [call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-call).

```py
baz[get_x()][get_y()] = value
```

As for *why* it's allowed, the simple reason is that it would be a bit silly and arbitrary for the Python developers to decide on a list of restrictions on the sub-expressions. The meaning of the assignment statement is well-defined so long as the left-hand-side is one of the required lexical forms, so the only reason to impose further restrictions on the sub-expressions of those lexical forms would be to try to prevent mistakes by the programmer.

On the other hand, code like `func_call()[index] = value` is not necessarily a mistake anyway, because the list that `func_call()` returns might well be referenced elsewhere, so the mutation will be visible through other references to that list.

Answer (score 1):

In python, not every value can be used of the left side of the assignment (so called lvalue). Basically, only 3 things can be lvalues:

- a name, like `abc`
- an attribute `any_expression.name`
- a subscript `any_expression[slice]`

Other values, like literals, arithmetic expressions, function calls etc cannot be used on the left side:

```
123    = 123 # no
a + b  = 123 # no
func() = 123 # no
```

See `assignment` in the grammar spec: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

Comment: That makes sense. I couldn't find these in the The Python Language Reference.

Comment: @quasimodo: added a link to the docs

Comment: For completeness, you missed target lists. The full list of things you can assign to is given in the documentation for [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).